# TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting below error when executing the python code given. Tried adding list but it still throws the same error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
--> 204                 dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j] ,dist[i][k]+ dist[k][j] )
 

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Please help in resolving this

```py
V = 4
INF = 99999

def floydWarshall(graph):
    dist = map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , graph)
    for k in range(V):
        # pick all vertices as source one by one
        for i in range(V):
            for j in range(V):
                dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j] ,dist[i][k]+ dist[k][j] )
    printSolution(dist)

def printSolution(dist):
    print ("Following matrix shows the shortest distances between every pair of vertices")
    for i in range(V):
        for j in range(V):
            if(dist[i][j] == INF):
                print ("%7s" %("INF"),)
            else:
                print ("%7d\t" %(dist[i][j]),)
            if j == V-1:
                print ("")
                graph = [[0,5,INF,10],
                         [INF,0,3,INF],
                         [INF, INF, 0,   1],
                         [INF, INF, INF, 0]
                        ]
floydWarshall(graph);
```

Comment: could you add an example input for `graph`, so we can run the code?

Comment: Why are you even using `map` for constructing couples? Just use a loop

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line
`dist = map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , graph)`

with this:
`dist = list(map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , graph))`

Because the `map()` function is just an iterable, it does nothing until you "consume" it.(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: This is still not sufficient to do ``dist[i][j]``. A list comprehension seems more adequate here, and would reveal the source of the bug as well.

Comment: still the same issue even after changing by adding list

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right